# Help with a dictionary+ application?

Tags: c#

I am thinking of making a dictionary application with some changes to suit my needs.But the problem is that I can't figure out how to get the word-list with their meanings.Any idea what I can do?
I found a word-list but it just had words not their meanings.
Edit- I am unable to add a comment.
Though I found this:
http://wordnet.princeton.edu/wordnet/download/
I am trying to see if I can use it in my app.

Comment: I think you're going to have a hard time finding a free dictionary that's in a format that's easy to parse.

Answer (score 0):

it's a bit generic question. Are you thinking to store all words in a database with their meanings? For example I imagine you could have two tables ( at least ), word and meaning, meaning has a FK to word so you could have multiple meanings for the same word.

is this ok as starting point?

Answer (score 0):

You basically should search for an open dictionary (check the license carefully!) you can access through an API or download a set of data to use it offline.

This sites should be helpful for a start:

- [Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Main_page)
- [Open Source Dictionary Downloads](http://a-z-dictionaries.com/Open_Source_Dictionary_Downloads.html)